# Send data from repository to view model in MVVM architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I'm confused about using MVVM architecture! In some tutorials, `LiveData` is stored in a repository and then passed to the `ViewModel`. In many others, `LiveData` is defined within a function of repository and passed to the `ViewModel` using the result of the function. But [Google says](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#livedata-in-architecture):

> It may be tempting to work LiveData objects in your data layer class, but LiveDatais not designed to handle asynchronous streams of data. ........ If you need to use streams of data in other layers of your app, consider using Kotlin Flows and then converting them to LiveData in the ViewModel using asLiveData(). .... For codebases built with Java, consider using Executors in conjuction with callbacks or RxJava.

I prefer to use Kotlin `coroutines` or `Flows`. But I do not know if in my case is really needed or not. I'm working on a chat application. When a message is received, a listener is called in the repository and the message data is received in it. (The listener runs in the background thread) Now I want to send the message object to the `ViewModel` and add it to a `LiveData` that stores the list of messages.

```
object ChatsRepo {

    fun listen(socket: Socket) {
        socket.on(Config.ON_MESSAGE, onMessage)
    }

    fun sendMessage(socket: Socket, json: String) {
        socket.emit(Config.ON_MESSAGE, json)
    }

    private val onMessage = Emitter.Listener { args: Array<Any> ->
        //This message object must be sent to ViewModel
        val message = Gson().fromJson(args[0].toString(), Message::class.java)
    }
}
```

I can easily do this using the higher-order function:

```
object ChatsRepo {

    lateinit var listener: (Message) -> Unit

    private val onMessage = Emitter.Listener { args: Array<Any> ->
        val message = Gson().fromJson(args[0].toString(), Message::class.java)
        listener(message)
    }
}
```

But is it better to use Kotlin `coroutines` or `Flows`? In some similar cases, a list needs to be sent to the `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 4):

> I can easily do this using the higher-order function.

Right, this is a callback you can use to notify `ViewModel` about new messages. Kotlin Coroutines help to avoid callbacks and to have a sequential code.

In your case the `onMessage` is a hot stream of data, we can convert it to a hot `Flow` using [`SharedFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/):

```
private val _messagesFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Message>(extraBufferCapacity = 64)
val messagesFlow: SharedFlow<Message> = _messagesFlow

private val onMessage = Emitter.Listener { args: Array<Any> ->
    val message = Gson().fromJson(args[0].toString(), Message::class.java)
    messagesFlow.tryEmit(message)
}
```

In `ViewModel` if need it is easy to convert it to `LiveData` using method [`asLiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#aslivedata):

```
ChatsRepo.messagesFlow.asLiveData()
```

Dependency to use `asLiveData()` extension function:

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0"

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

Comment: In this case, the advantage of using Flow is only to avoid callbacks? I know that coroutines is used instead of thread to execute part of the code in the background with better performance. But the onMessage runs on a thread that has already been created. Does using Flow instead of callbacks improve performance?

Comment: Can you explain what is extraBufferCapacity and why you set its value to 64?

Comment: @hyapp I don't think that using Flow in this case somehow improves performance.

Comment: @HusseinYaqoobi extraBufferCapacity is a number of objects, that can be buffered if consumer is slower than producer. It can be any number, depending on the case, even, if I remember correctly, infinity, but in the latter case you can get OutOfNemoryException.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Rxjava master, I will not recommend you to use flow/livedata. I think flow/livedata is designed for UI Reactive, not for underlying data transform. So you can use rxjava in data repository, and in viewmodel, you can convert it to livedata and use it.

Comment: There's nothing in `Flow` that would indicate that it's "designed for UI".

Answer (score 1):

Livedata was never design for reactive streams it was always been for `last layer (viewmodel to view)`, there were/are workaround when livedata was use with retrofit(using calladapter) and room(which google did it).
And now since the rise of coroutines recommended ways is to use `kotlin Flows` when dealing with business logic but things to be notice:
1- `regular flow` are not observables but livedata is observable.
2- it's not good to manage UI state with `regular flows` but you can do it with `livedata`.
3- livedata is `lifecycle aware` but flows are not. 
4- `livedata` is not reactive but `flows` are. 
5- `livedata` gives you the only latest value what it receives but `regular flows` throws values from bucket one by one

you might have notice i said alot of `regular flows` not `flow` cause there are other mechanism related to flows you can manage UI state that are `stateFlow` and `sharedFlow`. 
Stateflow is the replacement of `livedata` the downside is you have to code a little bit more to make it lifecycle aware cause it is not prebuilt and stateflow always gives you the last value it persists during the configuration changes or screen switching(fragment navigation).
`sharedFlows` is good for managing the one time event like toastMsgs, snackbar etc. `sharedFlow` was actually the replacement of `BroadcastChannels`.